# Slack API Angular Integration 200 error with 'OK response'

Tags: angular, typescript, http, slack

I'm trying to create a `Slack` app that communicates with my `angular` application, I feel as though I am very close to getting it working however I get the Below error:

[image: console]

Here is how I am calling my webhook from within my `angular` application:

```
   this.http.post<any>(webHook, JSON.stringify(message), options).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('res' + res);
      return res;
    }); // error here about json at 0 with ok response and 200 http
```

I am seeing the notification in the correct `Slack` channel but because I have an error interceptor in my angular application the error is causing problems in my angular application any help is greatly appreciated.

error-interceptor.ts:

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
// console.log('request was intercepted by error');

return next.handle(req)
.pipe(
  // Retry on failure
  retry(2),

  // Handle errors
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.error(error);

    let errorMessage = 'An unknown error occurred!';

    if (error.error.message) {
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    }

    this.dialog.open(ErrorComponent, {data: {message: errorMessage}});
    this.errorService.throwError(errorMessage);

    return throwError(error);
  }));

}
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to parse an already existing JSON object? Can you add the interceptor code?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I have added the interceptor, if I remove the interceptor all together I still get the error so thinking it doesn't come from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the `resonsetype` of the request to `'text'` as it was expecting a `JSON` response.

```
this.http.post(webHook, JSON.stringify(message), {headers, responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res => {
  console.log('res' + res);
  return res;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is returned correctly from the server, but it is likely that a string will be returned when it returns, and this will cause it to be false.
Example of correct return of information from the server:

bakend:

```
return OK('wellcome'); /// return {status:200,ok:false}
// This is a mistake and you should send the information as follows
string data='wellcome';
return Ok(data) // {status:200,ok:true}
```

Comment: I can't edit the server code as it is coming from the slack api